# Assigning special character as a value of a textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, escaping

I am adding a textbox dynamically like:

```
$('.myClass').html("<input type='text' class='txtVector' value='" + textValue + "'>");
```

Where I am adding the textbox value from a variable called "textValue". But the problem is that if the variable "textValue" contains a value with single quote(') or double quote(") like abcd'xyz or abcd"xyz the the textbox value looks like this value="abcd'xyz" or value="abcd"xyz". In this case the value truncates as soon as it gets the next quote. I mean textbox value will be only abcd not abcd'xyz. Can anyone suggest how to solve this?

Comment: You want to replace single quote character with empty string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `val()`:

```
$('.myClass').html("<input type='text' class='txtVector'>").children().val(textValue);
```

Or

```
$('.myClass').append(
    $("<input type='text' class='txtVector'>").val(textValue)
);
```

Or

```
$("<input type='text' class='txtVector'>").val(textValue).appendTo(".myClass");
```

See the [`val(string)` docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2). This has the advantage of handling other special characters correctly as well (`&`, for instance).

Comment: Are you sure the .html() will send back the input element? I though it would send back the $('.myClass') one.

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
$('.myClass').html(
    $('<input/>')
        .attr('type', 'text')
        .addClass('txtVector')
        .val(textValue)
);
```

or if you prefer:

```
$('.myClass').html(
    $('<input/>', {
        type: 'text',
        class: 'txtVector',
        value: textValue
    })
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe doing it in two times should do the job ?

```
$('.myClass').html("<input type='text' class='txtVector' value='' id='whatever'>");
$('#whatever').val(textValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var $html=$("<input type='text' class='txtVector'>").val(textValue);
$('.myClass').empty().append($html);
```